# Firebase Phone Authentication does not work after publishing app to PlayStore

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I have developed an application for Ios and Android, using firebase and react native with expo. When I publish the application in android and download it, authentication by phone number does not work, I understand that I must modify the SHA-1 that the playstore generated for me, however, in firebase my project is as "Web App" and not as an Android app. What settings do I need to make for authentication to work?